# IOS Ignoring ModalPresentationStyle and ModalTransitionStyle and presenting fullscreen

Tags: ios, ipad

My App is completely ignoring UIModalPresentationFormSheet and UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve. It is always popping up fullscreen and with the default transition.

It does it on my real app.
I then made a blank test app, and it does the same thing.

It is quite simple:
My AppDelegate loads KBViewController as the root view.
KBViewController tries to present a blank view controller (KBModalViewController).
The view in KBModalViewController.xib is set to the "FormSheet" Size

My View Controller:

```
@implementation KBViewController


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [self setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    KBModalViewController *m = [[KBModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:m animated:YES completion:nil];

    //Also tried the depreciated presentModalViewController, same result
    //[self presentModalViewController:m animated:YES];
}
```

I am using Xcode 4.61. I have compiled to ipad 5.1, ipad 6.1, and a real ipad 2 on 6.1. Same on all.

Comment: You don't need to edit the question to say it's fixed, just accept an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try..

```
@implementation KBViewController


    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

        KBModalViewController *m = [[KBModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [m setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
         [m setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        [self presentViewController:m animated:YES completion:nil];

        //Also tried the depreciated presentModalViewController, same result
        //[self presentModalViewController:m animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: I can't beleive I didn't catch that. I've used modal views countless times before. I guess my brain is shot at 5am. Thanks a bunch!

Boy do I feel dumb...

Comment: when your time is bad.. everything is going bad..:)

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this -

```
KBModalViewController *m = [[KBModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
m.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
m.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:m animated:YES];
[m release];
```